# how to implement image gallery with full screen mode option in sencha

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i want to implement some thing similar to the below link

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/gallery/

in  sencha touch 2.1

Can anybody give an idea how it can be done or is their any resources out their for the same to implement in sencha touch 2.1

what i thought was on touch of full screen mode i can push another view with image gallery in full view.......but this doesnt give real feel like zooming in from the panel....

Comment: May be modifying carousal can help you

Answer (score 0):

You need a carousel and a list... 
Set the list's inline property as wrap and load the images as list items... This will give you the pics below as you desire ... 
Use the carousel for the top image... On tap of the picture write a handler that will open a panel containing the same components for the full screen effect... 
Also give a showAnimation like pop up...

Hope it helps...